# etl-process: from python-dataframe to postgres with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, etl

I want to create tables in a Postgres database using Python's SQLAlchemy package and insert data from a dataframe into them. I also want to assign foreign keys and primary keys.

The following code creates the two tables, but in the schema "public" instead of the schema "my_schema".

Can anyone find the error?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

# Basisklasse für alle Tabellen definieren
metadata_obj = MetaData(schema="mein_schema")
Base = declarative_base(metadata_obj)

# Tabelle 2 definieren
class Tabelle2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tabelle2'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

# Tabelle 1 definieren
class Tabelle1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tabelle1'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    tabelle2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tabelle2.id'))
    tabelle2 = relationship(Tabelle2)

# Alle Tabellen in der Datenbank erstellen
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing metadata_obj as a parameter to declarative_base but not specifying it belongs to the metadata named parameter:

```
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata_obj)
```

declarative_base never knows the use the specified schema and falls back to the default schema of the connection.